# Is it possible to bind a local file to an Image control in Silverlight using XAML?

Tags: silverlight, image, file, bind, local

I'm writing an OOB app using Silverlight 5 and I want to be able to bind files from the local file system to an Image control, something like

```
<Image Source="e:/user_data/sprites1.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
```

Is this possible? If so how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it runs from desktop than yes, you can configure permissions in the project but if it runs from web browser, than absolutely it is not possible to access files from any folder on file system.

Here it is:
http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2010/04/20/tip-of-the-day-112-how-to-configure-your-silverlight-app-to-run-in-elevated-trust-mode.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I did actually set this when I first created the project, but the settings seem to have got lost somehow! Thanks for your answer